# Dynamic type loading in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using a protocol named Ethernet Industrial Protocol (EIP) and I use it to send and receive data from a Programmable Logic Controller (PLC).

The data is sent as hex values and in 2 byte sizes as the smallest. So when I ask for what is stored in a memory area in the PLC I get a 2 byte hex value back.

Currently I'm using hardcoded approach for parsing the data that comes back.
What I'm looking at is the ability to use a config file or something instead to tell what the string of bytes should look like.

Let's say I have 3 temperature readings and product type, the 3 temperatures are floating point and use 4 bytes per and the product type is an integer.
If I want to change it I need to change the program..

What should I read up on to be able to change this in for instance a config file instead of rewriting the application?
I want to be able to say that I have x number of instances of this type and the program should then parse it as that.

The program saves all the data it reads into a MySql database.
This is a snipet of the code that parses the values as the come in from the PLC.

```
Krakk = (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, bIndex)); bIndex += 2;
Small = (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, bIndex)); bIndex += 2;
Medium = (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, bIndex)); bIndex += 2;
Large = (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, bIndex)); bIndex += 2;
```

If I use a config file I would like to say something in the lines of:
name, uint, size and the program should then read that.
So for instance -> Krakk, uint16, 2 and then the program would know that it should change that out for this: Krakk = (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, bIndex)); bIndex += 2;

Comment: It's not clear how dynamic you need this to be. If you'd be writing a different type, that's still "changing the program". Why would you want to specify the number of *instances* of the type? It seems perfectly reasonable to have multiple types, one for each kind of data you'll read - that's fine. You could potentially have a config file to say which type to use. But it's not really clear what you'll be doing with the types afterwards, which makes it hard to give more concrete information.

Comment: Currently I'm just storing the values in a database so that we can look at the data collected for each product.

What I'm hoping to be able to do in the future is to add a new PLC and tell the program what I expect to get from the PLC and then parse it from there.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't quite see what you'd want to configure. Maybe if you could give an example of the configuration you'd like to provide, and how far you've got trying to implement it...

Comment: You can read the temperatures and product type from an xml or a text file, If you want these values to be changed. Is that what you want?

Comment: Today I have this hardcoded into the program:
Large = (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, bIndex)); bIndex += 2;

Where data holds the hex values and bIndex is the index of where in the string I am. For every value I want to read out of the PLC I need to add another line. 

If I for instance want that to be a int value instead of an uint I need to change the program. If all that could be dynamic, so that if I want to add 2 more datapoints I just add them in the config file, xml or otherwise.

Comment: But what would you then do with these dynamically read values? The "reading the data" part is simple, but how would you configure what you want to do with it? Please put this information in the question - and as I said, ideally show what you've already tried.

Comment: Updated.. I'm don't know quite how to explain it any other way.. 
I know enough to code the program with procedural coding and make it do what I want for now.. But if I could add datapoints and even PLC's just by adding to the config file which PLC to read from and what to read from it I wouldn't have to write the code for every instance of PLC or datapoints.

Comment: I think I need to sit down and make some test programs with a static string of hex values and try making a parser that reads a config string and parses it accordingly...

When I got some code that does something in the lines of what I want to do, I'll update and check if my approach is a good one..

Answer (score 0):

Even though I think you are already answering yourself, but here is my answer with some details:
You may need to create a new custom configuration section ([How to Create and Access a Custom Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)) with four properties as follows:

1. ReadingName (accepts string value and represents the name of the
   instance you want to read).
2. StartIndex (accepts integer value and represents the starting index from which you start reading the data bytes of the instance.)
3. Length (accepts integer value and represents the number of data bytes of the instance.)
4. Data Type.

In the app.config file you should add a section for each instance you want to read, then in your program you should read these values and act accordingly.

Comment: I will look into this and see if it is what I need. 
I kinda know what i want, but my inexperience stands in the way at the moment..